# Sitecore 7.0 Upgrade: The connection was reset error

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7

I have Sitecore 6.6 installed in the server.I am getting the below error while installing the update package for Sitecore 7.0 rev.130424. Has anybody else faced this issue? 
I get this error everytime i reach Processing 1936 of 2056 stage. 
[image: error]

Comment: It's been a while since I did an update to 7.0, but don't recall any issues. Is there any errors in the logs? How much time roughly is it taking to get to this this stage? It could be a timeout issue... Do you have your analytics and indexing disabled? That usually speeds up installs.

Comment: @jammykam I disabled indexing and analytics still it did not work. it does'nt actually take  more time at all but it gets stuck at the processing of 1936 changes

Comment: Anything in the windows event log?

Comment: It may be due to search. Do you use Lucene search on your original site, maybe the Searchcontrib module? You may need to remove/comment out search related code. Check the Sitecore logs in case there is messages logged there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved this issue. There were two things that we were doing wrongly.

1. Sitecore update installation wizard had some issue with Mozilla Firefox. The frame in the picture that says 'The connection was reset' is an iframe that keeps getting updated with the actions that were performed. If it does not get updated for a while then Firefox closes the connection. **So the solution is to use a supported version of Internet Explorer**.
2. The reason why it was stuck at process 1936 and not updating the iframe content was because sitecore was trying to update some files and it did not had privileges  required to update it. **So the solution is to give IIS worker process access to data and website folders. To do that select website folder -> right click -> properties -> security tab -> Edit -> Add -> Type IIS_WPG -> Check names -> Ok -> Then give full control to the IIS_WPG user -> Ok. Do the same to data folder and restart the installation.**